# Read 2 Bytes from 23GB file

Tags: java, large-files

Is there an easy and fast way to read two bytes from a 23gb large file in java?
The Problem is that read() method (FileInputStream) only supports int as offset. Reading chunks of size 2GB in memory takes to long...
There musst be a way to skip let's say 15.000.000.000 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`FileChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) and [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
FileChannel.open(file.toPath()).position(15e9).read(bb);
byte b = bb.get();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use nio [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) `position(long newPosition)` method. To get it, call `getChannel()` on the good old FileInputStream instance.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `RandomAccessFile` instead of a `FileInputStream` here.